# Is there a US credit union for foreign people?

Tags: bank-account, international-transfer, online-banking, credit-unions

I need to open a US account. I work for US based clients from Argentina and I need to receive payments and to transfer funds outside the US. I'm using PayPal, but I need another option to receive payment, some clients prefer to use transfers instead of PayPal.

To open a bank account I have to go to the US, but I've heard that credit union allow to open an account remotely, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, no, there isn't.

Unlike banks, US credit unions don't allow just anyone to become a member and open an account.  A credit union is required to have "field of membership" criteria that restricts membership to some group of people sharing a "common bond".  The common criteria are:

- Occupational: employees of a particular company, or people in a particular occupation
- Organizational: members of a particular club or similar organization
- Community: residents of a particular local geographic area

As a non-US resident, you wouldn't be eligible to join a community credit union.  And unless you are an employee of a US company, or member of a US organization, that is large enough to sponsor its own credit union (usually needs several thousand members at least), you are going to have a hard time meeting those criteria.  In principle there might be a credit union that serves members of your specific profession, and they might be allowed to let you join if they wished to do so, but those are likely to be more rare.

Source: http://www.ncua.gov/Legal/Documents/IRPS/IRPS2003-1.pdf, pages 1-10 through 1-11.